# ShellExecute get access to open folder

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, shellexecute

I'm using `ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", szSomeDirectory, 0, 0, SW_SHOWDEFAULT)` to open a directory in explorer.

I'm trying to open a directory that I would normally be prompted with `You currently do not have permission to access this folder.` and would give me option to get access and show a UAC prompt.

When I'm executing ShellExecute, Explorer gives me a error message saying `Access Denied`.

My program is running with administrator privileges but that doesn't seem to matter.

How can I get access to open this folder?

Comment: Try right clicking the program `.exe` and selecting `Run As administrator`. Depending on your OS, even though you are logged on as administrator it does necessarily mean all processes you start run with elevated privileges.

Comment: I've tried that. I think because the `"open"` verb is just telling explorer to navigate to the directory. Explorer is giving me the access denied message.

Comment: You probably need to run explorer elevated. This should do it: `ShellExecute(NULL, L"runas", L"explorer", szSomeDirectory, 0, SW_SHOWDEFAULT)`

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. Maybe this will help: `C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\` - Dir2 I don't have access to by default. I'm trying to open Dir3 in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

My user account didn't have access to the file.

My solution was to use `AccessCheck` before `ShellExecute` to see if I could access the file, and if I couldn't, use `SetNamedSecurityInfo` to add an ACE for the logon user account with full access.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the UAC level in the linker manifest for your program.

Take a look at this: [Strange file-permissions if apps run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605017/strange-file-permissions-if-apps-run-as-administrator)